# Using a value of a key within payload of MQTT message for AWS IoT S3 rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, iot

I would like to create an S3 key using values from a key within the payload.

So far I am able to make a key using

`${topic()}/${timestamp()}.json`

This results in a long chain of sub folders that I don't want. Instead I have the key "data_type" in my "payload" key whose value I would like to use. I tried doing

`${payload().data_type()}/${timestamp()}.json`

but it is not working.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer assumes that your MQTT JSON-payload contains the key `data_type`, e.g.:

```
{
...,
"data_type": "xxx",
...
}
```

---

If you replace

```
${payload().data_type()}
```

by

```
${data_type}
```

you should be fine.

---

Try this key:

```
${data_type}/${timestamp()}.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by modifying your `topic`.

Set your topic to : `topic/#`

So the message endpoint will be : `topic/xxx`
where xxx = data_type

Then you will be able to use the following S3 key in your IOT rule : `${topic(1)}/${topic(2)}/${timestamp()}.json` which will create a file (`dev/xxx/159859796xxx.json`) in your S3 Bucket.

For more info : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/topics.html